# Add two data table in one data grid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have two Data table. Data table1 and Data table2. I want to put these two data table in one data grid view. I don't want to merge them but i want to put them separately in one data grid view.

Comment: Why don´t you want to merge them? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: both datatable have different values that's why i don't want to merge them i just want to show both in data grid view

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/190503/displaying-two-data-tables-in-GRID-VIEW) which may give you some indication as to what is possible and what isn't possible. In order to effectively answer this question it would help to include the `DataTable` structures and if/how they link to each other.

Comment: And why excalty won´t you use two DGV instead?

Comment: is data table1 and data table2 have thesame column?

Comment: no both have different number of column